# Make regex ignore escaped questionmark

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get my regex working. I've a string which has escaped and non-escaped question marks. I've tried to find any guides or explanation of how I can create the regex which only selects the non-escaped question mark.

Example of question mark that SHOULD be found: `Hello, how are you?`

Example of question mark that should NOT: `Hello, how are you \?`

It only needs to select the question mark, as long it's not escaped, all text around that doesn't matter.

I've so far managed to make `\\\?`, but it only selects the escaped question mark, I need help to make it work as I've explained above.

Much appreciated, thank you!

Edit: For future notice, this was for a lookback-compatible engine, in this case PHP.

Comment: Use `(?<!\\)\?` - what is your regex flavor? If it supports lookbehinds, you can try this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume only a question mark can be escaped in your input.

Use

```
(?<!\\)\?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZ0kJ0/1).

Note that if it were JavaScript, or other languages that do not support lookbehind, you'd have to use something like `/(^|[^\\])\?/g`.

Comment: Yeah thanks, as it's a lookbehind compatible engine (PHP). This seems to work. So thanks :)